# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tmap’: object ‘writePNG’ is not exported by 'namespace:png'

Tags: r, dependencies, png, r-package, tmap

I am using R version 4.1.2 and am having issues loading the "tmap" package. I successfully installed "tmap" and dependencies, but keep getting error messages when trying to load it for use. My code and error output are below. Any idea what the issue is with png as stated below? I've already re-installed and loaded png

```
install.packages("tmap", dependencies = TRUE)
library("tmap")

> library("tmap")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tmap’:
 object ‘writePNG’ is not exported by 'namespace:png'
```

Comment: probably a wrong version of the png R package

Comment: I am new to R - I thought if I install.packages(png) that it would automatically use the most recent version? Is there a way to check/troubleshoot this?

Comment: look at the package description to know what package dependencies versions are recommended. you may also try yo install the latest version of png